# How to use Windows.Phone.Notification.Management.AccessoryManager class?

Tags: .net, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

So now with GDR1 we have all the API for smartwatches, but MS decided to block this API from regular developers. Only for OEMs.
Still is there any way I can use methods from this class? When I'm trying I always get System.UnauthorizedAccessException exception.
Any ideas? Should I add some compatibility declarations to the manifest?

```
try 
{
AccessoryManager.GetApps();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageDialog d = new MessageDialog(ex.ToString(),"Exception about access denied :(");
d.ShowAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like the Live Lockscreen API this is currently only available to OEMs and specific companies/people. Only MS can give your app special rights so that you can use the API.

Answer (score 0):

You should call AccessoryManager.RegisterAccessoryApp() first.